# vimrc tab behavior when noexpandtab and softtabstop is less than tabstop

Tags: indentation, tab-characters

## Questions

In the following example:

1. Why in the first line, a `\t` is inserted but only 4-col blank is displayed? Shouldn't it be `8` according to `tabstop`?
2. Why the two `<TAB>` hits in the first line and fifth lines have different results? (one is `09` and the other is `20202020`)

## .vimrc

```
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=8                             
set shiftwidth=4                                    
set softtabstop=4
```

## Text

I created the following text by first inserting 8 empty lines and then typing at the beginning of each line, so that there is no `shiftwidth` generated. (each 4-col blank below is inserted by hitting `<TAB>`):

```
1tab    done
2tabs        done
3tabs            done
4tabs                done
    1tab
        2tabs
            3tabs
                4tabs
```

## hex representation

Then I did `:%!xxd`, this is what I got (with some trailing newlines):

```
0000000: 3174 6162 0964 6f6e 650a 3274 6162 7309  1tab.done.2tabs.                                                                                                        
0000010: 2020 2020 646f 6e65 0a33 7461 6273 0909      done.3tabs..                                                                                                        
0000020: 646f 6e65 0a34 7461 6273 0909 2020 2020  done.4tabs..                                                                                                            
0000030: 646f 6e65 0a20 2020 2031 7461 620a 0932  done.    1tab..2                                                                                                        
0000040: 7461 6273 0a09 2020 2020 3374 6162 730a  tabs..    3tabs.                                                                                                        
0000050: 0909 3474 6162 730a 0a0a 0a0a 0a0a 0a0a  ..4tabs.........
```

### Related discussion

There are some pretty good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1878974/2160440) but I still don't understand what is going on in this particular case.

(PS: this thread was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34276561/2160440) but no comprehensive solution is found so I'm reposting it now.)

### Update

The [link](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/) from @EvergreenTree below is very helpful and almost solved my problem, however it seems not to answer my second question.

## Solution (adapted from [Christ's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6003/5833) below)

1. `tabstop=8` does not necessarily mean each `\t` is displayed as 8 columns, instead it means each `\t` is displayed as **ALIGNED** to 8 columns.
2. Similarly, `softtabstop=4` means each `<TAB>` hit (in contrast to `\t` for `tabstop` above) is displayed as aligned to 4 columns.
3. When `noexpandtab` is set, `<TAB>` hit may generate `\t`, spaces, or a mixture of them, depending on the current position of cursor. More precisely, it will advance to next position aligned with `softtabstop`. If this position is not aligned with `tabstop`, spaces will be inserted. If it is, `\t` will be inserted and redundant former spaces will be removed if needed. (see the video provided by @EvergreenTree below for an example of removing previously existed spaces).

Comment: Here is a vimcast on the topic: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/   I think it clarifies what all of the indentation options do.

Comment: It's indeed very comprehensive and clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: @wlnirvana if you have understood what's going on, would you care to write an answer explaining things? Might be useful for future visitors.

Comment: I was trying to but I suddenly found that my problem is not solved thoroughly... See update above.

Comment: You can post that as an answer, instead of putting it in the question.

Comment: But I think Chirst's answer should be chosen. Maybe I should have edited his answer instead of putting it in my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `softtabstop` to a value smaller than the `tabstop` value, Vim must insert spaces, as the tab when entered in insert mode may only be 4 chars wide. In contrast to line 1, the tab will move to column eight, even if there is some text in front of it.
This can be seen, by entering `o<C-U><C-V><Tab>` and then moving back to the first column and starting to insert some chars. Until you move over column 7, the tab after it will always stay.